# how to integrate jaspersoft with dynamic web app

Tags: java

I need to integrate `jasper` in dynamic web application and want to run in `wildfly` server..but it was throwing error.

```
Stacktrace:
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:95)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:198)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:449)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:359)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:334)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:321)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:652)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:358)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:403)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:347)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.jsp.JspFileHandler.handleRequest(JspFileHandler.java:32)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:326)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:812)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

JBWEB004060: An error occurred at line: 19 in the jsp file: /reportPage.jsp
JasperExportManager cannot be resolved
16:     
17:     JasperReport jasperReport=JasperCompileManager.compileReport(input);
18:     JasperPrint jasperPrint=JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,null);
19:     JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint,response.getOutputStream());
20: 
21:     response.getOutputStream().flush();
22:     response.getOutputStream().close();
```

I was trying to compile this web dynamic project and run war file in `wildfly` but it throws an error.

Comment: did you import JasperExportManager in your jsp file as `<%@ page import="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager" %>`

Comment: yes i add it now in jsp but it again throw an error.

Comment: it now show error as below

Comment: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: JBWEB004062: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

JBWEB004061: An error occurred at line: 20 in the generated java file
Only a type can be imported. net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager resolves to a package

Comment: how can i add a csv file as a input to jasper template ie abc.jrxml file  any body know about it please help me

Comment: http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/csvdatasource/

Answer (score 0):

Run this code on your controller requesting from font-end, Your problem will solve. Let me know if there is any more issue.

```
        try {
                InputStream jasperStream = null;
                //  when your jasper file is under classes/jasper repository
                jasperStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/jasper/ReceiveReport.jasper");
                JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperStream, params, new com.xx.xx.DataSource(columnData, columnNames));
                File pdf = File.createTempFile("Your Report File", ".pdf");
                JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(print, new FileOutputStream(pdf));
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
                byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) pdf.length()];
                try {
                    fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(pdf);
                    fileInputStream.read(bytes);
                    fileInputStream.close();
                } catch (Exception ignored) {
                }
                response.setContentType("application/pdf");
                response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename= Your Report File.PDF");
                response.setContentLength(bytes.length);
                response.getOutputStream().write(bytes);
                response.getOutputStream().flush();
                response.getOutputStream().close();
            } catch (JRException | IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

This is external custom DataSource class you need to include

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRField;
public class DataSource implements JRDataSource {

    private String[] fields;
    private Iterator iterator;
    private Object currentValue;

    public DataSource(List list, String[] fields) {
        this.fields = fields;
        this.iterator = list.iterator();
    }

    public Object getFieldValue(JRField field) throws JRException {
        Object value = null;
        int index = getFieldIndex(field.getName());
        if (index > -1) {
            Object[] values = (Object[]) currentValue;
            value = values[index];
        }
        return value;
    }

    public boolean next() throws JRException {
        currentValue = iterator.hasNext() ? iterator.next() : null;
        return (currentValue != null);
    }

    private int getFieldIndex(String field) {
        int index = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
            if (fields[i].equals(field)) {
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        return index;
    }
}
```